# How can I update state value immediately in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know **setState** in an async function. But If I need the value of state immediately, how can I get it?
This is my code

```
class OfficerPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state={
            counterList: [],
            currentCustomerValue: null,
            counterValue: null
        }
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.getAllCounters();
        this.getCurrentTicketId(this.state.counterValue) //cannot get value immidately
      }

      getAllCounters=()=>{
          API.getAllCounters().then((res) => {
            let allCounters=[];
            for(let i=0; i<res.length; i++){
              allCounters.push(res[i]);
            }
            this.setState({counterList: allCounters} )
         })
         .catch((err) => {
          this.setState({AuthErr : err.msg});
         });
        }


        getCurrentTicketId=(counterValue)=>{
            API.getCurrentTicketId(counterValue).then((res) => {
              this.setState({currentCustomerValue: res})
           })
           .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({AuthErr : err.msg});
           });
          }

          onChangeCounter = (event) => {
            console.log(event.target.value+" vall");
            this.setState({counterValue: event.target.value});
          };
```

Problem is **onChangeCounter** value does not update immediately, it changes after 2 iterations. How can I solve this?

Comment: You're accessing the state in the `componentDidMount`, where the value of `counterValue` is still `null`. Looks like you want to call the `getCurrentTicketId` function inside the `onChangeCounter` like this: `this.setState({counterValue: event.target.value}, () => getCurrentTicketId(this.state.counterValue))`;

Comment: yes it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### setState Callback in a Class Component

That’s the callback function that will be executed after the state value is updated. and you can call any other functions to get the latest state updates.

For namely:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: 0,
    };
  }
  
  // this.checkAge is passed as the callback to setState
  updateAge = (value) => {
    this.setState({ age: value}, this.checkAge);
// When the Age state has updated, this.checkAge will be executed without depending on the React render method.
  };

  checkAge = () => {
    const { age } = this.state;
    if (age !== 0 && age >= 21) {
      // Make API call to /beer
    } else {
      // Throw error 404, beer not found
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { age } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Drinking Age Checker</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={age}
          onChange={e => this.updateAge(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `componentDidUpdate` to get the latest and updated state if you are not familiar with `setState` callback function.